# what the condition for $P$ devided by $Q$.

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic

We consider two polynomial $P(X) =X^{4n}+X^{3n}+X^{2n}+X^{n}+1$ and $Q(X) =X^{4}+X^{3}+X^{2}+X+1$ So what  the condition for $P$ devided by $Q$.
we note  $P(X)= Q(X) H(x)+ R(X)$ if  $P$ devided by $Q$ we should have $R(X)$ since Q is $4$ degree polynomial $R(X)$ should be polynomial of  three or less degree .

Comment: Write $Q(x) = \frac{x^5 - 1}{x - 1}$ and $P(x) = \frac{x^{5n} - 1}{x^n - 1}$. What does this tell you about their roots?

Comment: Think about the complex roots.

Comment: If you don't know theorems about roots, you could try using euclidian division?